# Updating table schema by BigQuery API (python)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I use the BigQuery API following method to update schema:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch

I have updated a RECORD field type, but the subfields of the RECORD are updated in a different order than in the JSON file.
How can I keep on the same order?

Here is a part of the JSON:

At first, the schema was created as the following:

```
{
    "name": "report",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "ackTime",
            "type": "INTEGER",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
        },
        {
            "name": "closeTime",
            "type": "INTEGER",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
        },
        {
            "name": "closedBy",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then the schema was changed. The acknowledgedBy field was added, and the order was changed as the following (that's the way I got the dictionary from the source system):

```
  {
    "name": "report",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "ackTime",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "acknowledgedBy",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "closeTime",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "closedBy",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So, I tried to update the schema and change the order like I got the data from the source system.

In practice, the schema was updated as the following (the acknowledgedBy field was added to the end):

```
  {
    "name": "report",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "ackTime",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "closeTime",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "closedBy",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "acknowledgedBy",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
   }
```

Comment: Did you created it in the wrong order and you want to change it? Or did it have been created automatically in the wrong order, despite  your correct scheme definition?

Comment: Please see above. I have edited my post.

Comment: It doesn't tell me what changed the scema.